# Move the background image on mouse over (Single Parallax)

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I would like to make the background image move slightly on the X and Y axis when the mouse is in the "landing-content" DIV, it should move with the movement of the mouse.
it should move inverse. EG. Mouse move down, "landing-content" image moves up.

**HTML**

```
<div id="landing-content">
<section class="slider"> 
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/fVWomWz.png"></img>
</section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#landing-content {
overflow: hidden;
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/F2FPRMd.jpg);
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
max-height: 500px;
border-bottom: solid;
border-bottom-color: #628027;
border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

.slider {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 200px;
max-width: 1002px;
}

.slider img {
width: 80%;
padding-left: 10%;
padding-right: 10%;
height: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/uMk7m/

Any help would be apprecated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use the mousemove event, as shown in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/X7UwG/

```
$('#landing-content').mousemove(function(e){
    var amountMovedX = (e.pageX * -1 / 6);
    var amountMovedY = (e.pageY * -1 / 6);
    $(this).css('background-position', amountMovedX + 'px ' + amountMovedY + 'px');
});
```

It's just a quick example though, you'll have to play with the numbers yourself. ;)

Comment: Thankyou, but the image does not 'cover' the div anymore. any way to fix this?

Comment: For a movable background image you will need it to be say 20-30% bigger than the div I would think.

Comment: can this be done and "background-size: cover;" still be applied?

Comment: I don't see why not, but I'd definitely test it in some different browsers to be sure.

Comment: Any idea how you would do this?

Comment: It's possible that "background-size: cover" will scale down a larger image. You may not be able to use it. If the native size of the image is larger than the background though, you might be able to do without it.

Comment: background-size: should be set to 110%.   is it bossable to make the laptop move a few px when the background does?

Comment: Yes. The CSS may need changing for the laptop image though. For instance with position absolute, or relative. You'd need to select the laptop, and adjust it's position as required. E.g. `$('.slider img').css('left', amountMovedX + 'px');`

Comment: Thanks tom, is there a way to make it move with ease?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Modifying the css left and top properties is a good and easy way to move DOM elements.

Comment: You can still use background-size:cover if you scale that element simultaniously (`transform:scale(1.05)` or alike). Also consider using `transform:translate3d(...)` for the actual moving as it forces hardware acceleration on many modern browsers

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#landing-content').mousemove(function(e){
    var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 20;
    var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 20;
    $(this).css('background-position', x + 'px ' + y + 'px');
  });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uMk7m/2/

Comment: Thankyou, but the image does not 'cover' the div anymore. any way to fix this?

Comment: @Simon Make the div smaller, or use a bigger image. You're using the property `background-size: cover;` which makes the image fit the container, you could just remove that like this http://jsfiddle.net/uMk7m/3/, but it depends on what you're after.

Comment: This is the update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X7UwG/2/ - Any way i can center the image in the middle on the x and y axis?

Comment: @Simon not easily I don't think. You can have the original css state `background-position:center;`, and then I think you'd manually have to add the center offset during mousemove, like so http://jsfiddle.net/X7UwG/3/

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle. I think you will find what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/uXPkE/

```
$('#landing-content').mousemove(function(e){
    $(this).css('background-position',''+e.pageX/10+'px '+e.pageY/10+'px');
});
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the jquery library. http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/uXPkE/2/. this one should work.