# responsive bakground image like github 404

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop a page with the following background image on its bottom.[image]

What I'm inspired from is the [GITHUB 404 page's background](https://github.com/404). If you try increasing or decreasing the page size, it remains fixed with 100% width.

Any idea how can i achieve that effect with my image?

Comment: you are looking for parallax

Comment: You are indeed looking for parallax, here is a pen I created using this. Look at the code and you will find the plugin I used and how it works. [Demo](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/jEboey).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move the background image on mouse over (Single Parallax)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424317/move-the-background-image-on-mouse-over-single-parallax)

Comment: Guys, this is not what the OP is asking for...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by a full width div with a repeating image background.
HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/08pYU.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 221px;
}
```

Demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/uv2h3jj4/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
#fixed
{
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/08pYU.png');
  height:220px;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
  <div>
```